# Nested Classes in c++

Tags: c++, class, nested

```
class A{
public:
      template<typename Obj>
      class MyVec{
           //some methods...
      };
      MyVec<A> a; //-> doesnt work
      //vector<A> a; //using stl vector-> this works
};

class B{
public:
      void someMethod();
private:
      A::MyVec<A> b;
};
```

In the method, when I do sth like:

```
void someMethod(){
     //...
     b[0].a.pushback(element);
     //...
}
```

In class A if i use std::vector everything works properly. But when i use nested class it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you describe "doesn't work"? I'm sure the gurus here can spot this directly, but us mortals need compiler errors or somesuch ;) I'm also assuming `Class` is just a typo.

Comment: Well the code compiles successfully. But when i cout the pushed element, i dont get anything. But if i use std::vector i can get the the value that pushed.

Comment: Maybe show us some of the methods of `MyVec`? How is `operator[]` defined? How is `pushback` defined?

Comment: You mean you push back the value, but cannot retrieve it? Couldn't this indicate an error with your push method; an error unrelated to the above example?

Comment: I think the methods inside MyVec works properly, since i checked it with b.pushback(element);

Comment: I was thinking about some other problem like initialization, nested structure,etc.

Comment: If `MyVec` works, it's almost certainly an issue with your `operator[]` overload. Did you try to step through with `gdb` or some debugger?

Comment: Well when i say MyVec<A> a; in Class A it gives segmentation fault. But MyVec<int> a; works well. I mean i cant create with the same type... What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken your code and modified it as minimally as possible to get something that compiles. This seems to work fine. And so the error is not in the code you have shown us.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
  public:
    template<typename Obj>
      class MyVec{
        public:
        //My pushback just stores the value away for later.
        void pushback(Obj & o )
        {
          if( obj )
          {
            *obj = o;
          }
          else
          {
            obj = new Obj(o);
          }
          std::cout<<this<<" : Pushing object "<<&o<<std::endl;
        }

        //some methods...
        //My operator[] just returns the stored object.
        Obj& operator[](int i) { return *obj; }
        Obj * obj;
        MyVec() : obj( NULL ) {}
      };
    MyVec<A> a;
};


class B
{
public:
B()
{
   A an_a;
   b.pushback(an_a); //Better store one away since we access it in someMethod.
}
void someMethod()
{
     //...
     A element;
     b[0].a.pushback(element);
     //...
}
private:
      A::MyVec<A> b;
};

int main()
{
   //Test that it all works
   B outer;
   outer.someMethod();
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
0xbffffa5c : Pushing object 0xbffffa0c
0x3ec3c0 : Pushing object 0xbffffa2c
```

Which is what I'd expect. (one push in the constructor of B and one push to the internal object from someThing)

You can view the result here:
http://ideone.com/BX8ZQ

Answer (score 2):

You really should show the code inside MyVec. As a first guess, maybe MyVec's operator[] isn't returning a reference, so when you do b[0].pushback you're changing a copy instead of what you want; you wouldn't get that problem if you just tested with b.pushback()...